# Synchronize writing to a file at file-system level

Tags: c#, concurrency, file-io

I have a text file and multiple threads/processes will write to it (it's a log file).

The file gets corrupted sometimes because of concurrent writings.

I want to use a file writing mode from all of threads which is sequential at file-system level itself.

I know it's possible to use locks (mutex for multiple processes) and synchronize writing to this file but I prefer to open the file in the correct mode and leave the task to `System.IO`.

Is it possible ? what's the best practice for this scenario ?

Comment: Are all the processes running on the same machine, or are you accessing a file on a network share?

Comment: I don't think (but I'm not 100% positive) that there is a way to open a file in "wait-until-it-can-be-locked" type of sharing mode. I think the only way to do what you want is to use a mutex. Of course, if you're opening a file on a network share, that is not the solution either, you probably need to set up a server to take the log calls then.

Comment: @Lasse: All threads/processes on the same machine (windows)

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is just to use locks/mutexex. It's a simple approach, it works and you can easily understand it and reason about it.

When it comes to synchronization it often pays to start with the simplest solution that could work and only try to refine if you hit problems.

Comment: In fact I have not enough control over writing. I use `Debug.Write` and then `Flush` but it seems the content is not written to disk exactly after `Flush`. But I can choose the open/sharing mode and .NET writer object (for now I use `TextWriter`)

Comment: @Xaqron I think you could quite easily switch to a file writing mechanism that opened, flushed and closed the file. However, whether the performance would suffice would depend on what rate you wish to log, and how accurately you want the interleaving from the different processes to be represented.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, Windows doesn't have what you're looking for.  There is no file handle object that does automatic synchronization by blocking all other users while one is writing to the file.

If your logging involves the three steps, open file, write, close file, then you can have your threads try to open the file in exclusive mode (`FileShare.None`), catch the exception if unable to open, and then try again until success.  I've found that tedious at best.

In my programs that log from multiple threads, I created a `TextWriter` descendant that is essentially a queue.  Threads call the `Write` or `WriteLine` methods on that object, which formats the output and places it into a queue (using a `BlockingCollection`).  A separate logging thread services that queue--pulling things from it and writing them to the log file.  This has a few benefits:

- Threads don't have to wait on each other in order to log
- Only one thread is writing to the file
- It's trivial to rotate logs (i.e. start a new log file every hour, etc.)
- There's zero chance of an error because I forgot to do the locking on some thread

Doing this across processes would be a lot more difficult.  I've never even considered trying to share a log file across processes.  Were I to need that, I would create a separate application (a logging service).  That application would do the actual writes, with the other applications passing the strings to be written.  Again, that ensures that I can't screw things up, and my code remains simple (i.e. no explicit locking code in the clients).

Comment: If I cannot resolve it at file-system level, then using `IPC` is needed for `multi-process` scenario which is not a good approach for a simple logger (I don't think famous loggers do the job that way).

Comment: I agree that it's less than ideal, but there doesn't appear to be any automatic synchronization at the file system level. I could be wrong, but a close reading of the pertinent documentation doesn't reveal anything. If you come across something, please let us know. Also, what "famous loggers" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use [`File.Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx) with a [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) value set to `None`, and make each thread wait if it can't get access to the file.

Comment: I think that would cause an access exception unless there's a blocking call or wait handle.

Comment: That will indeed cause an exception.

Comment: @Xaqron can't test it at the moment, let me know what it does if you try it